# Wordpress - Use Dompdf in functions file

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

I am trying to do some PDF generation on my Wordpress site, I have an AJAX call that calls a function in my functions.php file but I currently can't even get the Dompdf library to load.

The location of my dompdf folder is `wp-content/mytheme/inc/dompdf`, here's my function:

```
function generate_pdf() {
  require_once(get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
}
add_action('wp_ajax_generatepdf', 'generate_pdf');
```

And my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: myobject.ajaxurl + '?action=generatepdf',
    data: pdfHTML
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I look in the network tab at the `admin-ajax.php` call, the response just shows this:

```
There has been a critical error on your website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.
```

If I comment out the `require_once` line and instead echo out the require path, it is displaying the correct path to `autoload.inc.php` in the response. I have `WP_DEBUG` enabled, but that generic error is all that I get in the response. Any ideas on what the issue might be or even just how I can get a more specific debugging response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `get_template_directory_uri` which is an absolute web-based path. Instead, you want to use [`get_template_directory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/) which will get you the file-system based path.

Also, if you are in a child theme, you might instead want [`get_stylesheet_directory`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/)

Comment: Silly me, that was it! Glad it was something simple, thank you!